# Android Studio inspect code via console

Tags: android-studio, static-analysis, lint

I'd like to know how to run the Android Studio inpect code tool (Analyse\Inspect code) via terminal and extract results back.

Also, it'd be great to enter the analysis criteria as a parameter (similar to a simple lint execution).

Thanks!

Comment: hey found any soltuion?